# Html is being tweeted along with the content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, socialshare

I am trying to post content from an array in Jquery and the content gets posted on twitter as shown below on a button click.

[image]

Also, when there are any special characters in the text, the entire text is not posted.

For example, the content is "This is our job as designers – to continue making decisions until the purpose of the design is perfectly clear. Then you are done." and it is posted as shown below.

[image]

Could you please help me how to resolve the two issues mentioned above.

Code for generating the content:

This function gets the quotes from the link and pushes it into the content array.

```
    function getQuotesFromWeb(){

     $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=40",            function(json) {
            json.forEach(function(val) {
            content.push(val.content + "--" + val.title + "");        
        }); 
      }); 
  };
```

This method changes the URL based on the quote being displayed.

```
function generateQuote()
  {     
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (content.length - 0 + 1)) + 0;
       $("#quotePlace").html(content[randomNumber]);   

     var linkRef = "http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + content[randomNumber];
      $('.twitter-share-button').attr('href', linkRef);
  };
```

Comment: You need to sanitise your input. We need to see the code that generates your `content` variable. We can't help you with what you've shown

Comment: I have added the code which generates the content.